# Codeigniter: problem extending Database Driver

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Im using Codeigniter 2.x and been trying to extend the database class and [followed the wiki](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Extending-Database-Drivers) but im getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MY_DB_mysqli_driver::where() in /system/libraries/Session.php on line 218

> Error: Call to undefined method MY_DB_mysqli_driver::where() in /system/libraries/Session.php on line 218

On line 218 of /system/libraries/Session.php:

```
$this->CI->db->where('session_id', $session['session_id']);
```

My extended class is just the example from the wiki:

```
<?php
class MY_DB_mysqli_driver extends CI_DB_mysqli_driver
{
    public function __construct($params)
    {
        parent::__construct($params);
        log_message('debug', 'Extended DB driver class instantiated!');
    }

    public function get_first($table)
    {
        return $this->limit(1)->get($table);
    }
}
```

Comment: As of 2020 Codeigniter 2 is no longer supported and I don't even know if extending the core is even a feature in ci2.

Comment: @marcogmonteiro you can extend the core in CI2. The wiki states that it works also for CI2

Comment: Couldn't you just extend the CI_Model?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw what model? i want to extend the database driver. there's no models in this issue.

Comment: as a test: if you replace all session variables with hard-coded variables.... would that work?

Answer (score 2):

The error you're getting is actually correct. I just downloaded version 2 to make sure of it.

You're extending the `CI_DB_mysqli_driver` when what you're actually adding to it should be in the active records library and not the database driver.

Instead of extending your `CI_DB_driver` create an extension of `CI_DB_active_record` and add the `get_first` functionality in it.

I must add that if that function is all you want to add to your core I wouldn't even bother to extend the core with it, since you're just trading one line by another line, there's no gain in it.

Also, most of these extensions can be done in a good base Model instead of hacking into the core.

Comment: Yep it's definitely a candidate for a model extension. I.E. My_Model.

Comment: I just used that function get_first() for the example. What i need to do is intercept all queries from active record class so i can use a different mysql server for reads and another for writes. Using a model is not feasible. I really need to extend the db driver/active record class.

Comment: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Extending-Database-Drivers

Comment: Well it says there on how to do it, I think you're doing it right, if you're getting an error than its probably a bug. We're talking about a 10 year old framework version that is not supported anymore so this is to be expected.